# QGIS creating shapefile of several points out of two Excel sheets

Tags: qgis, shapefile, distance, excel

I am about to create a QGIS file on which it should be visible which companies are working together. As source I have got two Excel tables.

1. Table = Distribution Centers
2. Table = Point of sales

I like to connect The point of sales (always several) with the associated distribution center. In the tables of the distribution centers you have the ID, and some (x/y) coordinates. In the Point of sale table you can find a ID, also (x/y) coordinates + a ID and which allows you to connect the Point of sales and the distribution centers (the second ID is the same like any of the distribution centers).

I want to separate the group of the distribution center and the related point of sales as one shapefile without searching manually in my Excel tables and creating 1 shape manually for every group...

I hope you will be able to understand my problem although my English is horrible.

---

My Lines are like this...

```
TDLinx-DC|TDLinx_-POS|Geometrie 
00421362|00421362|LINESTRING (2.30567 48.7321) 
00421362|00611434|LINESTRING (0.89378 46.4288)
00421362|00409507|LINESTRING (6.45527 46.359952)
```

Now it is like this. Might it be impossible to have a mixed point AND polylines layer?

```
TDLinx-DC|TDLinx-POS|Geo
00421102|00617429|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 7.34101 47.7495)
00421102|00256888|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 6.1812365 48.6876425)
00421102|00264459|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 5.0379298 47.3211782)
00421102|00264472|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 6.4946471 48.591343)
00421102|00264483|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 6.1618809 48.6763621)
00421102|00264501|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 7.7577037 48.5677807)
00421102|00264502|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 5.5904536 47.4484859)
00421102|00264503|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 6.1550176 47.6202079)
00421102|00264758|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 6.4474578 48.1758391)
00421102|00269360|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 6.0215766 47.2392361)
00421102|00269382|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 5.384374 49.1602425)
00421102|00269399|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 7.3564671 48.0791666)
00421102|00269478|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 6.8588071 47.6378244)
00421102|00429683|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 7.7465095 48.5839322)
00421102|00421102|MULTIPOINT (6.06043 48.70638, 7.34101 47.7495, 6.1812365 48.6876425)
```

Comment: No, you can not mix points and lines in one shapefile. That`s aganist the definition of shapefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Excel, you can create a CSV file with lines encoded in [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), e.g.

```
dist_center; pt_of_sale; wkt
center1; pt1; LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30)
center1; pt2; LINESTRING (40 30, 20 50)
...
```

Use Excel formulas to automatically generate the WKT text.

Load the CSV into QGIS using Add Delimited Text layer tool.

Comment: Hello Underdark, i guess this will be a good solution for my problems. The only problem actually is that Qgis dont want to open the text file I created as a Shape file: Der Layer file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/maue/Bureau/Versuch_Shape_Vorlage2.txt?delimiter=%7C&delimiterType=plain&wktField=Geom ist ungültig und kann der Karte nicht hinzugefügt werden  --> The layer file is invalid and can not be added to the existing map. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RouvenMaue Please paste the first few lines of your text file. (You can edit the question).

Comment: @RouvenMaue Well, two coordinates don't make a line. It needs at least start and end point - therefore 4 coordinates.

Comment: Oh well, I thought there will be a connection between the rows/lines. But it was excactly the problem. That works right now. It also works to have several lines in one shapefile. But one thing does not work: to combine in one text file POINT and STRINGLINE. --> TDLinx-DC|TDLinx-POS|Geo 00421102|00617429|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 7.34101 47.7495) 00421102|00256888|LINESTRING (6.06043 48.70638, 6.1812365 48.6876425) 00421102|00421102|POINT (6.06043 48.70638) is the problem, that I can not use stringlines and points as 1 layer? And how to solve that prob? Rouven